# Figures of Speech: Inversion, doubt

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion, figures-of-speech

This is a doubt from the poem Television by Roald Dahl and it is there in our 10 STD school textbook. I and my teacher had a bit of conflict with the figures of speech here:

```
...In almost every house we've been,
We've watched them gaping at the screen...
```

My teacher says that the above sentence is inversion, saying that the correct order is `We've been in almost every house...`, and that while indentifying figures of speech, we have to refer each line separately.

I argued that we can't consider it that way and that it is not inversion as the sentence is in proper order.

Please explain me what is right and what is wrong. Please give a complete analysis of the sentence also.

Thank you.

Comment: The two lines of the poem, if written as prose, would have a perfectly acceptable word order.

Comment: that's what I think, but I need a complete explained answer to be well justified

Comment: *In every town I've visited, I've seen children playing in the street*. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I tend to side with you. But notice that there is a reading of the first line where your teacher is correct. The two lines can be parsed: "We've been in almost every house; We've seen them gaping at the screen." The two-line sentence of the poem is *syntactically ambiguous*. Both your and your teacher's readings are acceptable and make sense.

Comment: @Silenus - That would change the meaning of the sentence entirely. They have *not* been in almost every house (that would be impossible.) The inversion, if there is any, is the second phrase with the first: "We've watched them gaping at the screen in almost every house we've been."

Comment: @medica: It does change the meaning, but perhaps it is possible that we have been in every house—for example, if the context dictates that this is only about every house in a certain street, or if it is a deliberate exaggeration, or whatever. But perhaps that doesn't fit the actual context, which I haven't seen?

Comment: @Cerberus - Given the context (or lack of), we don't know, but it's a familiar adverbial phrase, whose meaning does change if so rearranged. Fixing an inversion shouldn't dramatically change the meaning of a sentence. "In every town I've visited" is not equivalent to "I've visited every town...". It seems the *correction* (not that it's needed) would be, *"I've seen children playing in the street in every town I've visited."*

Comment: No, it’s **not** inversion, but something called **preposing**. This involves putting an element before the subject when its basic position would be after the verb. In your example, the preposed element is a preposition phrase adjunct which has been relocated (preposed) to the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @BillJ - That sounds like a good answer.

Comment: @BillJ: You're really focusing on specific terminology...that's fine, but you might not want to state terminology as an absolute fact, because it's just terminology. Different people use different terms in different ways, and that is not counterfactual. If they have good reasons for doing so... Don't fall for the 19th-century classification trap! Latinists used to make long lists of the different ways the ablative could be used, each with a different term.

Comment: @medica, I agree with you that the reading I gave above is unlikely, but it does exist. The impossibility of a state of affairs does not entail that we do not have words describing it. Also, as Cerberus pointed out, quantifiers like "every" (with or without a noun) can be, and regularly are, restricted by context.

Comment: @Cerberus I'm not falling for any trap, I can assure you! "Preposing" is quite a widely used term in modern grammar: [link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prepose); [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AMAgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=grammar+preposing&source=bl&ots=mLEUYefZ2u&sig=FPJmlXHQViYA7YA05QyTkPPPnhg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI5djzjbfMAhVHOBQKHTqIA9AQ6AEIUDAJ#v=onepage&q=grammar%20preposing&f=false)

Comment: @Silenus - I think you're making the mistake of confusing a prepositional phrase with a sentence. As I said, the main clause has no inversion. As BillJ states (I believe quite correctly), the prepositional phrase is preposing the verb of the main clause.

Comment: @medica, the so-called prepositional phrase "In every house we've been" is actually syntactically ambiguous. You can parse it as a straightforward prepositional phrase or as an independent clause (an *inversion* or *preposing* of "We've been in every house"). It just sounds funny and is hard to access because only Yoda would structure it that way: "In every house, Mr. Skywalker, we've been."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You and your teacher may both be right, although your reading is more likely to be that intended by Dahl.

Typical inversion is that between subject (*we*) and verb (*have*), which is not the case here. But you might call this a kind of inversion too, since the adverbial phrase *in almost every house* is normally placed after *be* in the sense of being present at a location. Then the first line is an independent sentence, and the second line is a second independent sentence. In formal prose, you would not use a comma between those sentences, then, but rather a full stop or a semicolon.

However, a more likely interpretation is this:

> In almost every house [that] we've been [in],
>
> we've watched them gaping at the screen.

We read this as an **omitted *that***. The result is that the first line is not a sentence but merely an adverbial phrase; the core of the adverbial phrase is *in almost every house*, and the *that* clause adds some information to this house, specifying that we are talking about only about those houses that we have been in.

This type of construction, with omitted *that*, is far more common than the one your teacher had in mind, so I think this is the best interpretation.